# How to cancel Air France itinerary and get a refund in cash?

Tags: air-travel, cancellations, air-france

I know this should be straightforward, but unfortunately it appears to be far from the case. All of the customer service numbers I have tried are currently closed.

I bought a return trip on the Air France website, around US$2000 in total. The first departure flight is scheduled for tomorrow afternoon. However, with the COVID situation I decided it wiser earlier this week not to travel. When I bought the trip I paid extra for a flexible option permitting cancellation with refunds until the first flight, anticipating such a situation.

The instructions indicate that through "My Booking" I can solicit a refund, but I cannot find any option. The instructions state that if not possible through "My Booking" I can fill out this form:

https://www.airfrance.us/cgi-bin/AF/US/en/local/customer/webform.do?webformId=assistance-remboursement

I did so three days ago, but I'm just checking now, and my flight (tomorrow evening) still appears active. I received an email when I sent the form, but it provides no details as to my particular request (not even my name).

I wanted to call customer support right now to confirm that I will receive a refund (at some stage ... I am not in a hurry), but did not find a single Air France call centre open in my country, nor in France, nor elsewhere with an international number. I would have to wait until tomorrow, which I fear will be too late.

Looking at the same form to solicit a refund in other languages:

https://www.airfrance.cl/CL/es/local/customer/webform.do?webformId=assistance-remboursement

The instructions are not the same. The Spanish version includes:

> Atención: antes de solicitar un reembolso o vale de viaje, asegúrese de haber cancelado su reserva antes de la fecha de partida de su vuelo.

Translated as:

> Attention: before soliciting a refund or voucher, be sure to have cancelled your booking before the date of departure of your flight.

This is not in the English version I originally filled out, and I did not do this. Revising "My Bookings", I see no option to cancel a booking, only to change the flight or the dates.

Has anyone had experience of this process? Do I need to explicitly cancel my booking before soliciting a refund via the form above? How could I cancel my booking online? (Perhaps there is a 24 hour number I can call?)

Again, I know this looks like it should be straightforward, but I've been at this a couple of hours, and am more or less lost. With no customer service available to call right now, and the flight tomorrow, I decided to ask here in case someone has experience of this.

Comment: Don’t remember how thinks look like on the Air France website or app, but on some sites to get a refund you actually go into the “change ticket” to do that. You may also want to che k both via the website and via the app just in case. Also, can you tell us the fare code (should be shown on the e-ticket receipt)? If you don’t find  a way to do it right away, you **may** be able to change the flight to a later date until you are able to cancel it, but check rules, some may not allow full refunds after a change.

Comment: Thank you! After about an hour trying to call and having the call randomly hung up, I eventually got through to a person in customer services and got the flight cancelled. I will be refunded in about 90 days. I would not have much confidence in the form I filled out above as my flight was active right up until boarding. My recommendation to anyone in a similar situation is to call (hopefully the lines are open).